# Django bulk_create raises "Database is in recovery mode"

Tags: python, django, postgresql

**Requirements:**

1. Upload ~15MB csv file and then `bulk_create`
2. One round it task `id` to 100k records.
3. Next round it will remove existing records and `INSERT INTO` again.

**My guess:**
I am suspecting that `sequence_id` overflow is the root cause of my problem
Because it used to be able to uploaded before this time, but broken just for now and could not be able to upload it again

Here is my postgres log:

```
2017-06-23 04:55:21.087 UTC [27896] LOG:  server process (PID 20529) was terminated by signal 9: Killed
2017-06-23 04:55:21.087 UTC [27896] DETAIL:  Failed process was running: INSERT INTO "sales_sales" ("imc", "order_number", "original_order_date", "count") VALUES ('1049129', '415000458', '2017-03-01T03:00:00+00:00'::timestamptz, 1), ('1113804', '415000457', '2017-03-01T03:00:00+00:00'::timestamptz, 1), ('1151620', '415000460', '2017-03-01T03:00:00+00:00'::timestamptz, 1), ('1522771', '415000462', '2017-03-01T03:00:00+00:00'::timestamptz, 1), ('2280038', '415000459', '2017-03-01T03:00:00+00:00'::timestamptz, 1), ('7374979', '415000461', '2017-03-01T03:00:00+00:00'::timestamptz, 1), ('399428', '415000618', '2017-03-01T03:02:00+00:00'::timestamptz, 1), ('399428', '415000619', '2017-03-01T03:02:00+00:00'::timestamptz, 1), ('1049129', '415000614', '2017-03-01T03:02:00+00:00'::timestamptz, 1), ('1059455', '415000636', '2017-03-01T03:02:00+00:00'::timestamptz, 1), ('1059455', '415000638', '2017-03-01T03:02:00+00:00'::timestamptz, 1), ('1075963', '415000605', '2017-03-01T03:02:00+00:00'::timestamptz, 1), ('1113804', '415000607', '2017-03-01T03:02:00+00:00'::timestamptz, 1), ('1137600', '
2017-06-23 04:55:21.090 UTC [27896] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2017-06-23 04:55:21.100 UTC [19656] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2017-06-23 04:55:21.100 UTC [19656] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2017-06-23 04:55:21.100 UTC [19656] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2017-06-23 04:55:21.134 UTC [27896] LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
2017-06-23 04:55:21.183 UTC [20539] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2017-06-23 04:51:40 UTC
2017-06-23 04:55:21.202 UTC [20540] postgres@uihspot FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2017-06-23 04:55:21.211 UTC [20541] postgres@uihspot FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
```

Update my situation refer to `COPY` issue
**Solution:**
`pip install django-postgres-copy`

```
@transaction.atomic
def postgres_copy(instance: UploadedFile):
    """
    Use COPY to do bulk INSERT INTO
    :param instance:
    :return:
    """
    import time  # PyCharm Bug 30May2017 It optimized and removed my line
    start_time = time.time()

    bkk = timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(instance.file.url, "original.csv")

    Sales.objects.all().delete()
    with open("original.csv", 'rb') as source_file:
        with open("utf8.tsv", 'w+b') as dest_file:
            contents = source_file.read()
            dest_file.write(contents.decode('utf-16').encode('utf-8'))

    in_txt = csv.reader(open('./utf8.tsv', "r"), delimiter='\t')
    out_csv = csv.writer(open('./utf8.csv', 'w'))

    out_csv.writerows(in_txt)

    sales = []
    copy_mapping = CopyMapping(
        Sales,
        "./utf8.csv",
        dict(
            imc='IMC Number',
            order_number='Order Number',
            original_order_date='Original Order Date',
            count='Demand Order Count'
        )
    )
    copy_mapping.save()
    result = time.time() - start_time
    logger.info(msg=f"Total Execution save_sale_records time --- {result} seconds ---")
```

And the original one

```
@transaction.atomic
def save_sale_records(instance: UploadedFile):
    """
    This file will download from minio. Since TemporaryUploadedFile class is not a File class
    Therefore it is not supported by csv reader. Python function read from real object
    :param instance:
    :return:
    """
    import time  # PyCharm Bug 30May2017 It opmized and removed my line
    start_time = time.time()

    bkk = timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(instance.file.url, "original.csv")

    Sales.objects.all().delete()
    with open("original.csv", 'rb') as source_file:
        with open("utf8.csv", 'w+b') as dest_file:
            contents = source_file.read()
            dest_file.write(contents.decode('utf-16').encode('utf-8'))

    sales = []
    with open("utf8.csv") as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file, dialect="excel-tab")
        for index, row in enumerate(reader):
            """
            OrderedDict([
            ('\ufeffWarehouse Code', '41CL'), 
            ('Warehouse Desc', 'แอมเวย์ ช็อป สีลม'), 
            ('IMC Number', '1113804'), 
            ('Order Number', '415000457'), 
            ('Original Order Date', '2017-03-01 00:00:00'), 
            ('Order 24 Hour Min', '09:42'), 
            ('Demand Order Count', '1')])
            """
            if index == 0:
                continue
            # Multiple lines for maintainer
            order_date = row[4].split(" ")[0]
            order_time = row[5]
            order_datetime = order_date + "-" + order_time
            date_obj = datetime.strptime(order_datetime, "%m/%d/%y-%H:%M").replace(tzinfo=bkk)
            utc_date = date_obj.astimezone(pytz.utc)
            sale = Sales(
                imc=row[2],
                order_number=row[3],
                original_order_date=utc_date,
                count=row[6]
            )
            sales.append(sale)

    Sales.objects.bulk_create(sales)
    result = time.time() - start_time
    logger.info(msg=f"Total Execution save_sale_records time --- {result} seconds ---")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the error log clearly says it's not your fault.

> 2017-06-23 04:55:21.100 UTC [19656] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because **another server process** exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
>   2017-06-23 04:55:21.100 UTC [19656] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.

Emphasis mine. But you are still doing this the wrong way! The right way to load large amounts of data into postgresql is using [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-copy.html)

> COPY moves data between PostgreSQL tables and standard file-system
>   files. COPY TO copies the contents of a table to a file, while COPY
>   FROM copies data from a file to a table (appending the data to
>   whatever is in the table already). COPY TO can also copy the results
>   of a SELECT query.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am now trying to understand your messages

Comment: Trying to use this https://github.com/california-civic-data-coalition/django-postgres-copy

Comment: You don't need that. You have shown in your other question that you knoww how to use the psql console. That's all you need

Comment: Glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone coming from Google, I faced this issue when trying to use `bulk_update` on a large number of entries (`bulk_create` probably also creates this issue).  I fixed it by specifying a `batch_size`:

```py
MyModel.objects.bulk_update(models, fields, batch_size=1000)
```